# Which is the name of the 40-pin connector of a PowerBook 100 (Apple)?

Tags: apple, connector, powerbook

I need to find a replacement for the 40 pin connector in the Apple PowerBook 100 mainboard. It has a female flat cable in the top and 2 alternated lines of pins in the bottom. Picture attached. If you also point me some seller who sell this specific component, it would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! Questions about where to buy replacement parts is generally discouraged: https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/168/4222  However, asking about the name or part number is on-topic (I think).

Comment: It would be helpful to replace the pictures with others, showing the whole connector/area - maybe with the cable you're talking about attached. And/Or information what use it is? , This close up makes it really hard to distinguish features, and I'm not inclined to open my powerbook to compare.

Comment: google edge card slot connectors should be available on any EE trading site like [Farnell](http://www.farnell.no) ... guessing from the pin count most likely IDE interface. In worst case when you do not have replacement you still can solder the flat wide cable directly on PCB ...

Comment: The internal hard disk connect appears intended for a [flexible flat cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable). Identifying a  compatible connector would depend on the cable pitch (measurable on the top) and the row pin pitch and spacing on the bottom of the PowerBook 100 printed circuit board. (The cable pitch is half the row pin pitch. Through hole connectors can be hard to find.

Comment: e.g. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/909/6205-1381160.pdf